# Create new columns based on similar row values

Tags: r

How do I create a new set of data frame columns based on matched row values?
For instance, for this sample data frame:

```
x<-data.frame(cbind(numsp=rep(c(16,64,256),each=12),Colless=rep(c("loIc","midIc","hiIc"),each=4, times=3), lambdaE=rep(c(TRUE,FALSE),each=2,times=9),ntree=rep(c(1,2),length.out=36), metric1=seq(1:36), metric2=seq(1:36)))
```

[image]

For when some parameter, e.g., lambdaE, I'd like to create new columns for metric1 and metric 2 based on whether lambdaE is TRUE or FALSE.
The data frame would look something like this:

```
x2<-data.frame(cbind(numsp=rep(c(16,64,256),each=6),Colless=rep(c("hiIc","loIc","midIc"),each=2, times=3), ntree=rep(c(1,2),length.out=18), metric1.lambdE.FALSE=c(11,12,3,4,7,8,35,36,27,28,31,32,23,24,15,16,19,20), metric2.lambdE.FALSE=c(11,12,3,4,7,8,35,36,27,28,31,32,23,24,15,16,19,20),metric1.lambdE.TRUE=c(9,10,1,2,5,6,33,34,25,26,29,30,21,22,13,14,17,18), metric2.lambdE.TRUE=c(9,10,1,2,5,6,33,34,25,26,29,30,21,22,13,14,17,18)))
```

[image]

Or alternatively for the parameter "Colless", a new set of columns for metric1 and metric2 for each level of Colless.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, looks like library reshape2 has a quick solution:

```
reshape(x, direction="wide", idvar=c("numsp","Colless","ntree"), timevar="lambdaE")
```

Comment: This `reshape` function is part of the `stats` package. There is no `reshape` function in `reshape2`.

Comment: So I noticed in the case of duplicates, the reshape function only takes the first instances and drops the rest. Is there a way to simply append the duplicated instances to the end of the data frame?

Answer (score 0):

melt and dcast of reshape2 can also be used:

```
library(reshape2)
mm =melt(x, id=c('numsp','Colless','lambdaE','ntree'))
dcast(mm, numsp+Colless+ntree~lambdaE+variable)
   numsp Colless ntree FALSE_metric1 FALSE_metric2 TRUE_metric1 TRUE_metric2
1     16    hiIc     1            11            11            9            9
2     16    hiIc     2            12            12           10           10
3     16    loIc     1             3             3            1            1
4     16    loIc     2             4             4            2            2
5     16   midIc     1             7             7            5            5
6     16   midIc     2             8             8            6            6
7    256    hiIc     1            35            35           33           33
8    256    hiIc     2            36            36           34           34
9    256    loIc     1            27            27           25           25
10   256    loIc     2            28            28           26           26
11   256   midIc     1            31            31           29           29
12   256   midIc     2            32            32           30           30
13    64    hiIc     1            23            23           21           21
14    64    hiIc     2            24            24           22           22
15    64    loIc     1            15            15           13           13
16    64    loIc     2            16            16           14           14
17    64   midIc     1            19            19           17           17
18    64   midIc     2            20            20           18           18
```